# Rails validation error not including attribute name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I know I can fix this issue with i18n, which I will try to do if I have the time, but for a quicker fix I was curious: Is there a way to add the attribute name to a rails validation error? For example, I have the following in my model:

```
validates_presence_of :name
```

The validation error rendered is `can't be blank`. I'd prefer it to say `Name can't be blank`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `errors.full_messages`:

```
<ul>
  <% @record.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
validates_presence_of :name, :format => { :message => "whatever you want" }
```

Comment: That simply will not work. You're mixing up the class-method-style validations with the key-based validations.

Answer (score 0):

Only -

```
validates_presence_of :name, :message => "Name can't be blank"
```

for `validates_presence_of` , error-locale is - "can't be blank"; attribute/property name is prefixed during validation. You can override this by above.
So, for your case, since property name is 'Name', error will automatically become "Name can't be blank".
To override the property name for all validation, you can use human_attribute_name(http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Translation/human_attribute_name)